# PayPal REST API Webhooks

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have successfully implemented (in the sandbox) a Login with Paypal integration that gives me OAuth credentials as outlined in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/ (I call the tokenservice to retrieve a token and can successfully make API calls).

Using this API, I have registered a webhook for certain events. My intent is to allow users of my integration connect to their Paypal accounts and then when transactions occur in their Paypal accounts my webhook would be called. Unfortunately in the sandbox this is not happening: I've successfully executed sandbox transactions and although those transactions fire a manually configured webhook they do not fire my programmatically configured webhook. Is what I'm trying to do possible, or must I use the IPN to do this?

Also, when I configure this webhook using the API and the token I obtained after the user logged in, I see the webhook URL inside MY account, not inside the customer's account. Is this the reason why I don't see the webhooks?

Finally, when I get a webhook I try and perform an API call so I can look up the originating data, but I receive the following error:

{ name: 'REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING',
message: 'Access token is missing required scope.',
information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING',
debug_id: '2b1818c88af3' }

is the API token returned by the token service not capable of API calls?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: No: gave up and just used a manually registered web hook. Seemed promising, but after reaching out to Paypal support and getting no meaningful response I moved on.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you manually set up those webhooks. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what could the alternative be. Does it work properly in live mode?

Comment: Ah, nothing really documented, but if you visit https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications, click on a specific REST API app (those are the only ones I've worked with), select the Live tab (by default I believe Sandbox is selected) and then scroll down and click on Add Webhook you should be able to specify a URL and then receive webhook POST requests. This works in sandbox and works in multiple live REST API apps as well.